# How to acquire lock on a RMI method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm new to RMI but I (should) know how to use locks, and frankly I do not quite get the whole RMI thing, I'm just not sure what concept I'm missing so the code does not get blocked.

It's been a while since I did concurrency, but afaik, something like this:

```
if (condition) {
    write.lock();
    //do something since it's inside the critical section
    write.unlock();
}
```

And so on. And I don't really need it to be a ReentrantReadWriteLocks or whatever, I just need for a method to get a lock and then free it. But I need to free the lock in another method, and this is where I stop understanding what I need to do (when it's code for rmi methods and clients and servers and all this I'm doing).

What I've got so far:

```
public synchronized void acquire (boolean exc) throws RemoteException {
    if (exc) {
        write.lock();
    else {
        read.lock();
        exclusivo = exc;
    }
}

public synchronized boolean setFree() throws RemoteException {
    if (read.tryLock()) {
        read.unlock();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then the client invokes one method to get the lock, makes its operations, and then uses the other method to free it. Obviously this is not finished, and I believe (though I'm not sure, and that's why I'm asking), that the read lock is done about right... But I have trouble "believing" it, even though I've tried it and it seems to work, I'm not sure if I'm missing something else.

That's one problem, the other is, I don't really know what to do with the write lock, since if I do write.tryLock, and it's free, it's going to get the lock, and then I'd... free it and return true I guess? but by the time the condition is returned, the lock could be used again, since it's a write lock? Something like that, not sure